# Java 8 / Fernflower Decompiler: Bug or Feature

Tags: java, decompiling, decompiler

OpenJDK 1.8.0_191

I compiled and decompiled a piece of code below using Fernflower.

```
public class Decompile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int VAL = 20;
        System.out.println(VAL);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
public class Decompile {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      boolean VAL = true;
      System.out.println(20);
   }
}
```

I'm confused, how did `VAL` become a boolean?

**UPDATE:**

In Intellij IDEA decompiled code looks like this:

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

public class Decompile {
    public Decompile() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int VAL = true;
        System.out.println(20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried other decompilers for comparison?

Comment: @scrutari yes, JDCore, CFR and Procyon show VAL as int

Comment: The `VAL` is a constant which gets inlined, so while there might be a record the variable existed, it probably doesn't know how to work out what it was.

Comment: P.S. if you like working at the bytecode level, ASM is worth a look, as it is the foundation for many other bytecode manipulation libraries. https://asm.ow2.io/asm4-guide.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bytecode is

```
L0
 LINENUMBER 5 L0
 BIPUSH 20
 ISTORE 1
L1
 LINENUMBER 6 L1
 GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 BIPUSH 20
 INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (I)V
```

As you can see the `BIPUSH` pushes `20` onto the stack, then `ISTORE` takes the value and store it into the local variable.

It's a `Fernflower` problem.

---

For your interest the output for bytecode version `55` is

```
int VAL = true;
System.out.println(20);
```

You can see decompilers can be wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue is that Java bytecode has no notion of booleans, byte, chars, or shorts (except in type signatures). All local variables with those types are instead compiled to ints. Boolean true and false are compiled to `1` and `0` respectively.

What this means is that the decompiler has to guess whether a given local variable was supposed to be a boolean or an integer type. In this case, the value `20` is stored in the variable, which will never be stored in a variable of boolean type in Java code, so it should be easy for the decompiler to guess that it is an integer type based on the context. But it appears that Fernflower's boolean guesser is not that sophisticated.

For what it's worth, this is an inherently hard problem. Especially when you consider that non-Java bytecode doesn't have to follow the same patterns that Java does. It is perfectly valid for bytecode to use the same variable in both integer and boolean contexts. [The Krakatau decompiler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) has a pretty sophisticated inference step for guessing whether variables should be booleans or not, but it will still get things wrong in situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

It works like that as `compiler` do some `optimization` during the generation of the `byte code`. As VAL = 20; is final and not changing, so it can put the `20` in place of `VAL` without `impacting` the functionality in the second statement. Now the `decompiler` has only `byte code` and when it goes to read the Byte code it found `20` as inline in the `second line`. Byte code generated by the code as below:

```
   0: bipush        20
   2: istore_1
   3: getstatic     #20                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   6: bipush        20
   8: invokevirtual #26                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
```